# Wordpress featured image set width automatic proportional height

Tags: wordpress, resize, thumbnails

I am resizing my featured images in the functions.php file. I am attempting with ex. "news" to have a set 500 width and auto height - but the outcomes are really weird cropped versions of the image [outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Xqy.png)

```
    if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        add_image_size( 'presentation', 9999, 1000, true );
        add_image_size( 'news', 500, 9999, true );
    }
```

To call the featured image I use this code

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
  the_post_thumbnail('news');
} 
?>
```

I am trying to have a max width of "500" and the height to be automatically proportional to that width without creating a cropped image.

I tried putting "500" on width and "auto" height but that just creates a "critical error".

Comment: Did you try passing `0` for the height?

Comment: Didn't work :-) Also regenerated thumbnails to make sure. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You say you don’t want a cropped image, but you pass `true` as the crop argument.

Comment: When I put in "false" gave no different result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a cropped image because you set the crop argument to true. Using the following code I got an image of 500x667 pixels that looks perfectly fine. Here is the link to the image that was created: http://klaasmaakt.nl/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/Anouk-Pines-2-500x667.jpg

And this is the code that produces it:

```
function add_theme_sizes(){
    if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        add_image_size( 'presentation', 9999, 1000, true );
        add_image_size( 'news', 500, 0, false );
    }
}
add_action("after_setup_theme", "add_theme_sizes");
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a solution, but still not working here. I don't really know what to do! Even if I replace the code I am using with yours - and also regenerate thumbnails, still nothing. Thanks so much tho!

Comment: And what happens if you use this code and then upload the image again? Maybe something is wrong with your regeneration of thumbnails…

Comment: If it is still producing the wrong image, then try this code on a fresh wp install and fresh theme. At least then you can rule out that it has something to do with server level configuration.

Comment: Using the code and re-uploaded the image, also tried using different thumbnail regeneration plugins! So I'm sure the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: My server doesn't allow me several WP-installs so I can't try a fresh install. I'm sure your solution is good for my problem so I will mark it as solved - and use it with my next theme on another WP-install. Thanks so much Klaassiek :-)

Comment: Look into setting up a local web server. https://www.alphr.com/set-up-local-web-server/